Copy “latest files” from source to Sharepoint using KNIME
I’m trying to create a workflow to move the “latest files” in a landing zone (ftp location) to a sharepoint folder. i’ve got a workflow to find the latest files, but i’m struggling to come up with a way to take my table of file paths and use it as an input to the Transfer Files node.

so the solution turned out to be the "Transfer Files (Table)" node. i populated a table with the source file paths (as a Path type variable), and created a variable with the target location (as a String) and fed the table as an input and the variable as a variable (along with source and destination connections) to the node. It took the source path happily and used the folder variable to control the destination path.

Maybe it will help you to connect workflow variables to Transfer Files node? I see that in the node there is a tab "Flow Variables" where you can specify source location - path.
Maybe the "Transfer Files (Table)" node will also work for you?
